# Missing function(x) in defined function

Tags: r, function, sapply

I understand that in the following

```
aa <- sapply(c("BMI","KOL"),function(x) as.formula(paste('Surv(BL_AGE,CVD_AGE,INCIDENT_CVD) ~', paste(colnames(s)[c(21,259,330,380)], collapse='+'))))
```

I am missing `x`
but i really don't understand how and where to insert it to be correct.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I will try.. Im trying to apply     `Surv(BL_AGE,CVD_AGE,INCIDENT_CVD) ~SUKUP+HDL+SYSTM+PREVAL_DIAB, data=c` for two columns of my data frame (`BMI and KOL`). I expect `aa` to return me something like this `Surv(BL_AGE,CVD_AGE,INCIDENT_CVD) ~BMI+SUKUP+HDL+SYSTM+PREVAL_DIAB, data=c` and `Surv(BL_AGE,CVD_AGE,INCIDENT_CVD) ~KOL+SUKUP+HDL+SYSTM+PREVAL_DIAB, data=c` . But instead i have only `$BMI
Surv(BL_AGE, CVD_AGE, INCIDENT_CVD) ~ SUKUP + HDL + SYSTM + PREVAL_DIAB
$KOL
Surv(BL_AGE, CVD_AGE, INCIDENT_CVD) ~ SUKUP + HDL + SYSTM + PREVAL_DIAB`

Comment: Sorry in advance, i would be able to reproduce an example data. I just can not figure out where i miss `x`

Comment: Very difficult to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Making this an answer instead of a comment due to amount of text.

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to iterate over a list of variables, which you want to add (each in turn) to a set of independent variables in a survival model. The issue in the code you gave is that you don't give `x` a place. There are several approaches to do so.

The first one is very similar to what you're doing, and creates the formulas. I demonstrate this using the 'cancer' dataset:

```
library(survival)
data(cancer)

myvars <- c("meal.cal","wt.loss")

a1 <- sapply(myvars,function(x){
  as.formula(sprintf("Surv(time, status)~age+sex+%s",x))
}
)
#then we can fit our models
lapply(a1,function(x){coxph(formula=x,data=cancer)})
```

In my opinion, this is a bit convoluted and can be done in one step:

```
models <- lapply(myvars, function(x){
  form <- as.formula(sprintf("Surv(time, status)~age+sex+%s",x))
  fit <- coxph(formula=form, data=cancer)
  return(fit)
})
```

Using the code you started with, we can simply add 'x' to the vector of dependent variables. However, this is not very readable code and I'm always a bit nervous about feeding column indices to models. You might be safer using variable names instead.

```
aa <- sapply(c("BMI","KOL"),function(x) as.formula(paste('Surv(BL_AGE,CVD_AGE,INCIDENT_CVD) ~', paste(c(x,colnames(s)[c(21,259,330,380)]), collapse='+'))))
```

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what i want to do! Thank you for understanding and the code which i will try to digest! But maybe you know where is this space for `x` in the function shown above? Thank you!!!

Comment: Heroka, thank you so much! You save my week which i was trying to do it! You are cool! :) I voted for response, but it will not appear because I'm dummy, anyway thank yoU!

Comment: You're welcome! It helps that I've solved very similar issues for my own research, so have some idea what you want to do. But I agree with other commenters that your problem wasn't easy to understand without some outside knowledge.

Comment: Yes, I know, sorry for that and thank you for helping :)

Comment: @AnnaGorald: The SO interface is designed for concrete expressions of approval in the form of checkmarks and upvotes.I suspect Heroka would appreciate both of those affirmations as much as seeing the comment-"thanks".